# Cannot connect Cubes using MDX Sample Application

Tags: mdx, sample

I have SQL Server 2000 and Analysis Services installed on one VMWare Image. The "MDX Sample Application" can connect to the AS and see all the cubes defined. I clone the VMWare Image to another copy and change the IP. Now, when I open the "MDX Sample Application" in the new VM I cannot see any cube ???

I have also developed a .NET program to run mdx query against the cube, it works when connect to the original VM, but when query against the new VM, I got the following exception

Can not run sql statement "SELECT {[Measures].[Workflow Count]} on COLUMNS FROM [Workflow In Progress]" : Error=>The cube 'Workflow In Progress' does not exist, or it is not processed

Have anyone know how to make MDX Application to see the cubes ???

Answer (score 0):

Check in the new VM if the AS is working properly. Maybe you need execute a re-process in the cube or adjust the metadata to adapt to the new environment. You could make a database's backup in the original VM and a restore in the new VM.

Comment: AS services is all working. I have also re-process the cubes. Still not working. Can you show me how to change the metadata ?